# What's wrong with this syntax for getting length of longest row in table?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table that is populated from a JSON object.  The result is a table with an uneven number of cells in each row.  I'm working on a script to automatically append empty cells to each row so that there is a uniform number.  My problem is figuring out the length of the longest row in the table.  Below is my attempt at this.  However, I keep getting errors that the row is undedefined (e.g. "cannot read property length of undefined").  What have I done wrong?

```
function countCells() {
var columnCount;
$("#MarketsTable tr").each(function () {
    columnCount = Math.max(columnCount, $(this).cells.length);
})
return columnCount;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing basic DOM/JavaScript with jQuery.

Replace `$(this).cells.length` with either `$(this).children('td').length` or `this.cells.length`

http://api.jquery.com/children/

Answer (score 3):

I've made two changes to the code below. First I've declared columnCount as  0 in case the issue is related to passing NaN to Math.max. Secondly $(this).cells has been replaced with its vanilla counterpart.

```
function countCells() 
{
    var columnCount = 0;
    $("#MarketsTable tr").each(function () {
        columnCount = Math.max(columnCount, this.cells.length);
    })
    return columnCount;
```

}

Comment: Good catch. JavaScript does indeed return `NaN` from the `Math.max` function in this case.

Comment: Good catch indeed.  I just figured that out the hard way.

Comment: I gave mblase75 credit for the answer since he was first.  But you deserve a +1 for NaN.